# How can I "rotate" a relationship in laravel most efficiently?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

Im building an ecommerce website in Laravel. I have an **attributes** table filled with the attribute information, like "Color" and "Size". The **attribute_values table holds all the attribute values like "red", "blue" and "XXL".

Since I want to re-use the attributes I don't create a new attribute set per product, but I link all the attribute values to the products with the pivot table **attribute_value_product**.

The model relationship structure is:

```
Attribute -> hasMany -> AttributeValue
Product -> belongsToMany -> AttributeValue
```

The tables are as follows:

```
products
--------------------------------
| id | name            | price |
--------------------------------
| 1  | Example product | 200   |
--------------------------------

attributes
--------------
| id | name  |
--------------
| 1  | Color |
--------------

attribute_values
-----------------------------
| id | attribute_id | value |
-----------------------------
| 1  | 1            | Red   |
-----------------------------
| 2  | 1            | Blue  |
-----------------------------

attribute_value_product
----------------------------------------
| id | attribute_value_id | product_id |
----------------------------------------
| 1  | 1                  | 1          |
----------------------------------------
| 2  | 2                  | 1          |
----------------------------------------
```

The controller code (a bit simplified) looks like this:

```
public function show($id) {

  $product = Product::where('id', $id)
    ->with('attributeValues.attribute')
    ->first();

  return view('product')->withProduct($product);

}
```

the JSON result when I return the **$product** variable from the controller looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Example product",
    price: 200,
    attribute_values: [
        {
            id: 1,
            attribute_id: 1,
            value: "Red",
            attribute: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Color",
            }
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            attribute_id: 1,
            value: "Blue",
            attribute: {
                id: 1,
                name: "Color",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, this is kinda 'nasty'. When I retrieve lots of attributes for lots of products the attribute get's loaded for every value. When I only need it once actually. Also the way the data is structured is "wrong" in my opinion.

The preferred output I would like to see is:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Example product",
    price: 200,
    attributes: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: "Color",
            values: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    attribute_id: 1,
                    value: "Blue",
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    attribute_id: 1,
                    value: "Red",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

So the values would be loaded per attribute per product. Is there a (Laravel) way to structure the relationships in a way that I can retrieve the data in the latter format while still keeping the database schema I have?

I'd rather not loop over all the items every time I need to retrieve the attributes. Especially when querying for lot's of products with some other relations.

Comment: Show your models, please. Since `attribute_value_product` is a pivot table, you don't need a relationship with that table. You'd just reference the relationship from products - attributes with the pivot table. See https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: The models are in the first code block. They are Product, Attribute and AttributeValue. Attribute has many AttributeValue and AttributeValue belongs to many  Product. I don't have a relationship with the pivot table. It is there because there is a relationship between AttributeValue and Product.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually provided any controller code to help you ensure that you achieve the result that you are looking for but here are a few ways I would consider tackling this issue. But you will have to decide what would fit your coding style.

---

**Method 1:** Use the [HasManyThrough](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) Relationship on your `Product::class`

> Laravel's `$this->hasManyThrough()` relationship was intended to allow
>   you to access a nested relationship which fits your use case.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get all of the attributes for the product.
     */
    public function attributes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Attribute', 'App\AttributeValue');
    }
}
```

And use `Product::with('attributes.attributeValues')->first()`

> The use of dot notation above is to prevents n+1 issues by also eager
>   loading the nested attributeValues relationship. [see the Eager Loading Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

---

**Method 2:** Use an [Eloquent Resource](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources)

> Essentially, this is a model presenter which gives you the ability to
>   control the data provided returned via an API endpoint.

Eloquent Resources can be created via a console command

```
php artisan make:resource ProductResource
```

Which will generate a `ProductResource.php` file in the `app\Http\Resources` directory.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ProductResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        // This will use the Default Eloquent Model toArray methods
        $resource = $this->resource->toArray(); 

        // Now you can append in any custom fields that you need.

        if($this->whenLoaded('attributeValues'){
            // whenLoaded is used here to dynamically append this attribute only when the relationship has been eager loaded
            $resource['attributes'] = $this->resource->attributeValues->groupBy('attribute.name');
        }

        return $resource;
    }
}
```

> The use of `$this->whenLoaded` above accomplishes two things:
>
> 1. Limits N+1 errors (only for the `$product->attributeValues` and not the nested relationship of `$product->attributeValues->attributes`)
> 2. Allows for reusability of the `ProductResource::class` in situations where `Attribute` and `AttributeValue` are not
>      loaded/needed.
>
> Note: This line `$resource['attributes'] =
>   $this->resource->attributeValues->groupBy('attribute.name');` could
>   very well be replaced with calls to an [Eloquent Resource
>   Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-resources#resource-collections) with additional nested Resources and/or
>   ResourceColletions, if you decide to fully adopt the Model Presenter
>   pattern.

Finally in your controller you would do something like the following:

```
// Use of dot notation here will eager load the attributes as well avoiding potential n+1 problems

$product = Product::with('attributeValues.attribute')->first()

return new App\Http\Resources\Product($product);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Regarding the first method. Is there a way to do a has many trough pivot?

Comment: Not sure if you would like to just access the pivot table values which can be done here, `$this->hasManyThrough('App\Attribute', 'App\AttributeValue')->withPivot('attribute_id', 'value')` to add in columns from the `AttributeValue` table. Which you could access like so `$product->attributes->first()->pivot->value`, or if your database structure is complicated and makes it difficult to map the keys and table names to get the desired relationship?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to look up Eloquent Resources. It's basically a way to format your models when transforming them into an array.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class Product extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'price' => $this->price,
            'attributes' => $this->attribute_values->mapToGroups(fn($item, $key) => [
                [
                    'id' => $item->pivot->id,     // color id
                    'name' => $item->pivot->name, // color name
                    'values' => [
                        'id' => $item->id,
                        'attribute_id' => $item->attribute_id,
                        'value' => $item->value,
                    ]
                ]
            ])
            ->flatten(1),
        ];
    }
}
```

```
use App\Http\Resources\Product as ProductResource;
...
$product = Product::with('attributeValues')->first();

return new ProductResource($product);
```

Since I don't have your exact structure, I can only do guesswork. Just play around with the collection grouping methods until the data takes the format you want.

- [Eloquent Resources](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-resources)
- [Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#available-methods)